# SXA Search showing 400 Bad Request error (Infinite Loading)

Tags: sxa, search-facet

Working with Sitecore 9 (Update 1), SXA 1.7.1 and Azure Search.

Components added on the page: Map, Location Finder, Search Results (all components have same search signature).

I am facing this issue only in the `fr-FR` site I have created in SXA. I created a page in `fr-FR` and all the mentioned component on it. When I try to search for any location, the `Search Results` component does not load any results instead just shows the loading symbol. The console is throwing an error saying `400 Bad Request`. 
[image]
[image]

I checked all the items used in this scenario like Scopes, Facets or Rendering Variants. I found out whenever I add `Distance` Facet in the component `Location Finder` it breaks the search and throws 400. **Reminder**: It is working fine in other languages.

Search query:

```
https://mylocal.com/fr/sxa/search/results/?l=fr-FR&s={1AB997C8-36F9-4A14-81CD-02801D89B7CF}&itemid={839D6B67-A046-4E84-9F12-6E1BDDB4197C}&sig=&autoFireSearch=true&v={0EA6CE1F-3008-4783-95BF-E550C4CC2182}&p=20&g=48.856614|2.3522219000000177&o=Distance,Ascending&site=mylocal
```

[image]

**Log:**

```
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.BadRequestException
Message: Error in the request URI, headers, or body
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure
   à Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
   à Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.Search(String expression)
   à Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.Search(String expression)
   à Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Search.Azure.LinqToCloudIndex1.Execute(CloudQuery query, Int32& countDoc, Int32& totalDoc, Dictionary2& facetResult)
   à Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Search.Azure.LinqToCloudIndex`1.ExecuteTResult
   à Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Controllers.SearchController.GetResults(String v, String q, String s, String l, String g, String o, Int32 e, Int32 p, String sig, String site, String itemid)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException
Message: {"error":{"code":"","message":"Invalid expression: Unrecognized 'Edm.Geography' literal 'geography'Point(2,2908303 48,8870341)'' at '26' in 'geo.distance(geolocation, geography'Point(2,2908303 48,8870341)') lt 200' with reason 'Expecting token type \"Number\" with text \"\" but found \"Type:[7] Text:[,]\".'.\r\nParameter name: $filter"}}
```

Comment: There must be an exception somewhere. Please check sitecore.log, search.log and console for errors. As far as I remember we did major change in Azure Search logic in 1.7.1. Can you upgrade and test?

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I am using SXA 1.7.1. I mentioned the wrong version, its a mistake on my behalf.

Comment: What about normal and search logs? Any errors there?

Comment: Hi @DawidRutkowski, I have added the log also, please check. Thanks.